# How to get the exact location of an html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the exact location of an html element, and output the address of that element, the logic goes like this.

```
<div id="foo">
   <article>
       <div>
          <p>you found me</p>
       </div>
   </article>
<div>
```

So that is the sample html, now lets say the user click something on that mark up, in this case lets say the user click the 'p' tag. how do I write my JavaScript to output the address of that 'p' tag.

```
     function getAddress(){
         // code here
         console.log('the user click the ')
         console.log(address)
     }
```

Desired output:

```
      // Console
      log: the user click the
      log: #foo > article > div > p
```

Comment: whats the logic behind this any search algorithm? or you want to backtrace until parent comes with id?

Comment: @omi basically I want to backtrace until parent comes with id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var path = '';
    $('#foo').on('click', '*', function (e) {
        path = $(this).prop("tagName");
        $(this).parents().each(function () {
            path = $(this).prop("tagName") + ' > ' + path;
        });
        alert(path);
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
})
```

[Sample fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pwdxwry2/)

**UPDATE**

To add the `id` attributes:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var path = '';
    $('#foo').on('click', '*', function (e) {
        path = $(this).prop("tagName").toLowerCase();
        $(this).parents().each(function () {
            let id = $(this).attr('id');
            path = $(this).prop("tagName").toLowerCase() + (typeof id != 'undefined' ? '#'+id : '') + ' > ' + path;
        });
        alert(path);
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pwdxwry2/1/)

**UPDATE on Uppercase Tag Names**

Based on MDN

> In XML (and XML-based languages such as XHTML), tagName preserves case. On HTML elements in DOM trees flagged as HTML documents, tagName returns the element name in the uppercase form. The value of tagName is the same as that of nodeName.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted, but why are the strings are in all caps?

Comment: @MarvenWilsonSDonque, see my update for the answer to your question about uppercase tag names.

Comment: @MarvenWilsonSDonque, not sure why you marked my reply as the answer and then changed your mind. So much for saying 'thanks' :(

Comment: @ Frank Fajardo sorry men I got confused, I thought I marked your answer, your code is what exactly what I am looking for, thank you so much..

Comment: @ Frank Fajardo I got cofused, sorry, I did not changed my mind..

Answer (score -1):

I am using jQuery and created this code snippet. Click on **P tag**

```js
jQuery("p").click(function(){
  var parentEls = $(this).parents()
  .map(function() {
    return this.tagName;
  })
  .get()
  .join(">");
  alert(parentEls);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
   <article>
       <div>
          <p>you found me</p>
       </div>
   </article>
<div>
```